# Force settings button on Chrome for Android on Samsung devices using AOSP rom

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, chrome-for-android

Is there any way i can force settings button to appear on Chrome for Android on a Samsung Galaxy S4 after flashing to any AOSP ROM (Current: SlimKat 8.9). I found out that Chrome does not create a Settings button which you can find on other devices that has the navigation bar instead of hard keys. Other apps work fine and has the settings button appear.

[image: Settings button on Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

i just got a Galaxy Note and I noticed that the button was missing; however, this tablet comes with a physical menu button that you can use for that purpose